# Flutter: The method "call" was called on null - error repeated multiple times

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am creating an application on Flutter linked to Firebase on Visual Studio Code. The app was running the code attached perfectly. I then changed the `_pageOptions` list to contain the Home, Finance and Info widgets instead of simply text widgets. When running the amended code, the error below was flagged. I then changed the code back to the state attached where it was previously working. However, I was still presented with the same error.

**I am unable to copy the files into the issue, but the error causing widget is below:**

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:nrithyakala_finance/screens/finance%20manager/finance_master.dart';
import 'package:nrithyakala_finance/screens/information/info.dart';
import 'package:nrithyakala_finance/services/auth.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  //_selectedPage holds value of current page
  int _selectedPage = 0;
  //_pageOptions holds index values of each page
  final _pageOptions = [
    Text("HOME"),
    Text("FINANCE"),
    Text("INFORMATION"),
  ];
  //creates instance of AuthService class
  //AuthService class declared in auth.dart file
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("NrithyaKala Finance App"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[400],
        //actions holds list of widgets within app bar
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            onPressed: () async {
              //accesses signOut function
              await _auth.signOut();
            },
            label: Text("LOGOUT"),
          )
        ],
      ),
       body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        //list of items to display on nav bar
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text("Home"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
            title: Text("Finance"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
            title: Text("Info"),
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        //sets current index to value of selected page
        currentIndex: _selectedPage,
        //changes colour of selected item
        selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
        onTap: (int index) {
          //sets home page state to that of selected page
          setState( () {
            _selectedPage = index;
          });
        } 
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**ERROR IN FULL: The error below is printed multiple times in the debug console**

```
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification>:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold 
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      new StringBuffer  (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:56:3)
#1      new _PrefixedStringBuilder 
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:810
#2      TextTreeRenderer.render 
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1162
#3      DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep 
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1709
#4      DiagnosticsNode.toString 

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
```

**OUTPUT OF FLUTTER DOCTOR**

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (5 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\snehz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\snehz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

• No issues found!
exit code 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: can you show whats inside _pageOptions[]? This should be an array of widgets.

Comment: I feel you removed _pageOptions when trying to go back to previous state.. but forgot to remove it from the `body` of scaffold.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri Hi, thanks for the help! I've added the whole code above. The _pageOptions list is still present, however unfortunately the error is still appearing.

Comment: Since you returned it to the state where it was working, and it's no longer is working, it may be due to incremental rebuilds.  That feature isn't perfect.  Try shutting down the app completely and starting from scratch in the state where it *was* working.  Or if necessary, restart even VSCode!